# Ignoring user input while other computations are happening

Tags: c++, input, cin, getline

I am writing a connect 4 game, and the general flow of the game is:

1. Ask where user wants to play
2. Play user move
3. Move on to computer's turn
4. Run algorithms to decide computer move
5. Play computer move
6. Repeat

The problem I'm running into is that while the computer is deciding its move (which may take up to 10 seconds or so) if the user inputs any information and presses enter, the next time the computer runs the function to ask the player for where it wants to play, the accidentally values are taken as input and the game is then ruined.

So if the player were to enter, for example, this stream of data:

1 (return)
4 (return)
2 (return)
alskdf (return)
jklgo[2 (return)

the computer would take those 5 pieces of input and treat them as what the player entered as the column he/she would like to play in for the next 5 turns.

What I need is some way to ignore any arbitrary amount of user input while another function is performing calculations, but once that function is done calculating what it needs to, any user input from then until that calculation function is called again should be treated as valid input.

Here is the relevant chunk of the main() function from the program:

```
while (turn < w_*h_)
{
    if (whosTurn == 1) //player's turn
    {
        playerTurn(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed); //function that asks for user input
        printScreen(board);
        if (printWin(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed, pDisc)) break;
    }

    else if (whosTurn == 2) //computer's turn
    {
        compTurn(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed); //function that does the long calculations
        printScreen(board);
        cout << "The computer played in column ";
        printColor(colPlayed+1, GREEN);
        cout << "\n\n";
        if (printWin(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed, cDisc)) break;
    }

    if (whosTurn == 1) whosTurn = 2;
    else whosTurn = 1;

    turn++;
}
```

The parts relevant to my question are `playerTurn()` and `compTurn()`.

Answer (score 1):

before calling playerTurn try cin.ignore() to clear the input stream before prompting for more input

Comment: Will that work if the player were to input some number of characters, press enter, then input some more characters, then press enter again?  And what if the player actually doesn't input anything when he's not supposed to, would the true input which I atually want to take be ignored?

Comment: Just tested putting both cin.cear() and cin.ignore() in a couple different places and they didn't actually seem to make any difference at all, which surprised me.  As in when I put a cin.ignore() somewhere, it's not like only the first input was ignored and the rest were taken, not even the first input was ignored

Comment: did you pass any parameters to the can.ignore() it should 2 parameters - the first is the max number of characters to discard, the second is a delimiting character (EOF is default), e.g. cin.ignore(10,'\n'); will throw out the first 10 characters or until the newline character is encountered